# How to fix errors when install gem "devise"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I add gem "devise" in rails app, then run "bundle install", and it shows error like this::

> /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2:
>   warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:4:
>   warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3:
>   warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:5:
>   warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in
>   rescue in _decrypt: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
>   (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage) from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in
>   `_decrypt' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in
>   'decrypt_and_verify' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in
>   'decrypt_and_verify' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in
>   decrypt from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in
>   'read' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in
>   read from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in
>   'config' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in
>   'options' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in
>   'method_missing' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in
>   'key_exists?' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:10:in
>   'find' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in
>   'block in ' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
>   'instance_exec' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
>   'run' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in
>   'block in run_initializers' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in
>   'block in tsort_each' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in
>   block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in
>   block in each_strongly_connected_component' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   each' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   call' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   each_strongly_connected_component' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in
>   tsort_each' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in
>   tsort_each' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in
>   run_initializers' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in
>   initialize!' from
>   /home/hoanglien/Rails/dating-app/config/environment.rb:5:in '
>   from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
>   require' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
>   block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in
>   register' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>   require_with_bootsnap_lfi' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in
>   require' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in    block in require' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in    load_dependency' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in    require' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in
>   preload' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in
>   serve' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in
>   block in run' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in
>   loop' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in
>   run' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in
>   ' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in
>   require' from
>   /home/hoanglien/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in
>   require' from -e:1:in ' **

In my gemfile:

```
    "https://rubygems.org" git_source(:github) { |repo|  "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby "2.5.1"
    gem "rails", "~>5.2.3"
    gem "puma", "~> 3.11"
    gem "mysql2", ">= 0.4.4", "< 0.6.0"
    gem "sass-rails", "~> 5.0"
    gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"
    gem "turbolinks",    "~> 5"
    gem "jbuilder", "~> 2.5"
    gem "bootstrap", "~> 4.0"
    gem "bootstrap-sass", "3.3.7"
    gem "jquery-rails", "~> 4.3", ">= 4.3.1"
    gem "bootsnap", ">= 1.1.0", require: false
    gem "i18n"
    gem "i18n-js"
    gem "config"
    gem "devise"
   group :development, :test do
     gem "byebug",    platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   end
   group :development do
     gem "web-console", ">= 3.3.0"
     gem "listen", ">= 3.0.5", "< 3.2"
     gem "spring"
     gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
   end
   group :test do
     gem "capybara", ">= 2.15"
     gem "selenium-webdriver"
     gem "chromedriver-helper"
     gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw,    :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
   end
```

Comment: try updating you're `bundler` version `gem update bundler` and try bundle.

Comment: try running `spring stop` and then `bundle install`

Comment: sorry, when I run "rails  generate devise:install" it shows errors like up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your RubyGems loaded in your PATH? try running as

```
bundle exec rails g devise:install
```

Comment: thank you, it done. but when i generate a controller , it shows same errors like up, pls help me.